# Compare two directories.Good Design Pattern

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

I recently encountered an interview question."How to compare two directories".
My Answer was to use Tree Like Structure.(Generic tree).At every level,node can be a leaf or it may contain child nodes.Point Parent to first child and first child to next sibling.
The Interviewer then extended this question to "What if data is large and it cannot be in memory at once ".I could not figure answer to this question.Can someone suggest ?

Comment: Directories already have a tree structure. There is no reason to duplicate this structure in memory.

Comment: I am only given two directories and I have to tell if they are identical.What should be the approach then?(No use of existing tools/scripts)

Comment: Well, with my definition of identical, I would use `return dir1.getAbsoluteFile().equals(dir2.getAbsoluteFile()`. If that is false, then the directories are not identical, since they don't have the same name, or don't have the same parent directory. What is your definition?

Comment: Means same with respect to content.No of files in directories are same.No of sub directories are same and at every level.

Comment: I guess the interviewer expected "recursion". Check that number and names of files is same. Check that number and name of directories is same. Repeat recursively for each pair of subdirectories.

Comment: yes,but if data cannot be stored in memory all at once,then will this approach works?

Comment: You would need a damn huge number of subdirectories and files to exhaust the memory.

Comment: @NikhilSaxena Recursion wouldn't strictly require that you store everything in memory, only the current path. Some (if not most or all) API's may only give you the list of files / directories in the current directory rather than giving a space-efficient iterator, but storing that for every node in the recursive structure will still be more efficient than storing everything.

Comment: Do you mean that you two directories are the same if the structure and the files are the same, but the directory and file names may be different?

Comment: E.g. comparing dir A and B, both with 2 sub-directories, is it possible that the first sub-directory in A matches the 2nd in B and the 2nd in A the first in B, so A and B would be equal? If that's the problem you can define unique ordering of directory content and sort both directories at each node before comparing.